# Transform a flatten object to hierarchical

Tags: javascript, typescript

EDIT: My previous post was confusing IMO, so I edited this post only relevant information.

I have `userInput` object and I want to convert it's shape or type so that it can match with the `IUser` interface.

```
const userInput = {
  email: "test@test.com",
  handler: "tester",
  password: undefined,
  bio: "this is my bio",
  birthDate: 817283
}
```

into to something

```
const updatedUser: IUser = {
  accountInfo: {
    email: "test@test.com",
    handler: "tester"
  },
  personalInfo: {
    bio: "this is my bio",
    birthDate: 817283
  }
}

interface IAccountInfo {
  email?: string;
  handler?: string;
  password?: string;
}

interface IPersonalInfo {
  bio?: string;
  birthDate?: number;
  interests?: string[];
}

interface IUser {
  accountInfo: IAccountInfo;
  personalInfo: IPersonalInfo;
}
```

All undefined values are omitted.
I tried this with `merge` function from `lodash` library it failed to do so.

Comment: do you have some data and wanted result?

Comment: Lodash includes an excellent `merge` function that (I believe) will accomplish exactly what you're looking for: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#merge

Comment: That's all my code @NinaScholz

Comment: @WilliamLewis I updated my post with the exact trasnformation I want. Please take a look.

Comment: How general do you want the solution to be?  Hardcoded to exactly `IUser`?  Or something more general like [this](https://tsplay.dev/8w8V9m)?  If that works for you let me know, otherwise please elaborate on the scope of the solution you're looking for.

Comment: If you want it hardcoded to `IUser` then maybe [this version](https://tsplay.dev/GNlyrm)?   I'm happy to write up an answer but I need some more feedback about scope.